# Recorrer carpetas en python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import os, glob
from obspy.core import read

for fname in glob.glob('BC.*'):
    arch=fname.split('.')
    print "<==== ", fname
    #  Quita la extension (.msd), si existe
    if(len(arch) > 7):
       del arch[-1]
    newName = '.'.join(arch)
    st = read(fname)
    segmentos = len(st)
    # cuenta el numero de segmentos del archivo para hacer el cambio en cada uno de ellos
    for i in range(0, segmentos):
        st[i].stats.network=arch[0]
        st[i].stats.station=arch[1]
        st[i].stats.location=arch[2]
        st[i].stats.channel=arch[3]
    print "====> ", newName , " Ok"
    st.write(newName, format="MSEED")
    print " --- ", fname, " [x]" 
    os.remove(fname)
```

Funciona bien, solo que para correr el script tengo que estar dentro de la carpeta que hará el cambio, y es tedioso estar corriendo el script dentro de cada carpeta.

¿Como podría hacerle para que haga el recorrido de todas las carpetas sin tenerlo que estar poniendo dentro de ella?

Los carpetas las tengo así:

```
C:\Datos\TEST1\DatosTest1
        \TEST2\DatosTest2
        \TEST3\DatosTest3
```

Answer (score 3):

Escribí este código para listar todos los archivos en una carpeta y sus subcarpetas:

```
import os
import sys
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, isdir, join

def listdir_recurd(files_list, root, folder, checked_folders):

    if (folder != root):
        checked_folders.append(folder)

    for f in listdir(folder):
        d = join(folder, f)       

        if isdir(d) and d not in checked_folders:
            listdir_recurd(files_list, root, d, checked_folders)
        else:
            if isfile(d):  # si no hago esto, inserta en la lista el nombre de las carpetas ignoradas
                files_list.append(join(folder, f))

    return files_list
```

La función se usa así:

```
filez = listdir_recurd([], 'D:\test0', 'D:\test0', []) # esto lista todos los archivos
filez = listdir_recurd([], 'D:\test', 'D:\test', ['D:\\test\\t1', 'D:\\test\\t2']) # esto omite las carpetas 'D:\\test\\t1' y 'D:\\test\\t2'
filez = listdir_recurd([], 'D:\test', 'D:\test', ['D:\\test\\t1']) # esto omite la carpeta 'D:\\test\\t1'
```

La lista `filez` contiene los nombres y las rutas absolutas de todos los archivos encontrados, por lo que ya puedes aplicarles tu algoritmo. En tu caso se usaría como:

```
filez = listdir_recurd([], 'C:\Datos', 'C:\Datos', [])
```

Más info, aquí: 
http://programacionamartillazos.blogspot.pe/2016/01/listar-los-archivo-en-una-carpeta-y-sus.html

Answer (score 2):

Conozco dos formas de recorrer directorios donde se muestra cada carpeta que hay dentro.

**Forma 1**

```
import os
rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Directorio encontrado: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
```

**Forma 2**

```
import os

rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=False):
    print('Directorio encontrado: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
```

Ambos recorren los directorios y subdirectorios contenidos. Puedes adaptar tu código utilizando estas formas.

Comment: Eduardo, creo que debes indicarle que si intenta abrir el archivo usando solo `fname` le arrojará un error, para que funcione bien es necesario hacer un join con el directorio raíz: `os.path.join(dirName, fname)`

Comment: @César creo que no entendí a lo que te refieres, podrías explicarme?

Comment: @César no tengo instalado 'obspy.core' para probarlo. A la noche podría hacer unas pruebas.

Comment: A lo que me referìa es que en el código original de @Armando hace un `st = read(fname)`, el problema es que usando tu método generará error si haces:  `st = read(fname)` ya que tienes que hacer antes un join con la ruta raíz, es decir: `st = read(os.path.join(dirName, fname))` :-)